# python - regex for matching text between two characters while ignoring backslashed characters

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I am trying to use python to get text between two dollar signs ($), but the dollar signs should **not** start with a backslash i.e. \$ (this is for a LaTeX rendering program). So if this is given

```
$\$x + \$y = 5$ and $3$
```

This is what should be outputted

```
['\$x + \$y = 5', ' and ', '3']
```

This is my code so far:

```
def parse_latex(text):
    return re.findall(r'(^|[^\\])\$.*?[^\\]\$', text)
print(parse_latex(r'$\$x + \$y = 5$ and $3$'))
```

But this is what I get:

```
['', ' ']
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Can there be ``\\`` denoting a backslash? Like `\\$\$x + \$y = 5$ and $3$`

Comment: \\$ will be a \$ with a \ before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex that excluded escaped characters:

```
>>> text = r'$\$x + \$y = 5$ and $3$'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\$)([^$\\]*(?:\\.[^$\\]*)*)(?=\$)', text)
['\\$x + \\$y = 5', ' and ', '3']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zA7zE2/1)

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/7xzBwE)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<=\$)           # Lookbehind to assert previous character is $
(                 # start capture group
   [^$\\]*        # match 0 or more characters that are not $ and \
   (?:            # start non-capturing group
      \\.         # match \ followed any escaped character
      [^$\\]*     # match 0 or more characters that are not $ and \
   )*             # non-capturing group, match 0 or more of this non-capturing group
)                 # end capture group
(?=\$)            # Lookahead to assert next character is $
```

Comment: Lookarounds are still needed since matches between `$`s are overlapping.